# javascript i++ for every 10

Tags: javascript

javascript `i++`, how to do some code `add 10` for every time?

I need 1,11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91.

```
for(i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
   //I need 1,11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91
}
```

Comment: [This reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference) might help. So might [this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
for(i = 1; i < 100; i+=10) {
   //I need 1,11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add 10 in each loop.

```
for(i = 1; i < 100; i +=10) {
   //I need 1,11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this ->

```
for(var i=1; i< 100; i=i+10) {
   console.log(i);
}​
```